# Windows Updates - Does Not Install, how can I remove it

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, sql-server-2005

Everytime I shutdown my Windows XP, it comes up with the following screen which says

> Turn Off with Installing Updates

(Of course, it also gives me an option as follows, "Click here to turn off without installing updates.")

When I do a normal shutdown asking it to "Install Updates and Turn It Off", it doesn't actually install the updates. Each subsequent time I try to shut down the PC, it still prompts me to "Turn Off with Installing Updates".

[image]

I managed to find out that the install was this:

> Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Service Pack 3
>   (KB955706) update 1 of 1 ....

[image]

When I click on the Installing Updates icon (the yellow icon, that appears on the task bar near the clock), and install it, it tries to install but fails:

[image]

Why is this install alone failing?

Secondly, if it's not possible to ascertain why the installation is failing, can I at least ensure that it's removed from the list of possible installs so that each time it does not ask me to install it?

Comment: OK, the images, I guess have been messed up. I uploaded them to imageshack and put them in the <img> tags, but no one can read it. I will fix them soon as I have to rush to catch a train.
And oh, Happy Holidays everyone!

Comment: Try to install the service pack manually and see what errors it comes up with.

Comment: It might help if you could share the relevant parts of your \Windows\WindowsUpdate.log file, and any events from the system/application log.  These might tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Some useful Microsoft articles:

> [How to Troubleshoot Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602/)
>   [Microsoft Windows Update Troubleshooter](http://v4.windowsupdate.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/) (use Internet Explorer).

If you consider yourself knowledgeable about using Windows, your best bet is probably to use the free utility [Dial-a-fix](http://wiki.lunarsoft.net/wiki/Dial-a-fix):

> Dial-a-fix (hereafter known as "DAF")
>   is a collection of known fixes gleaned
>   from Microsoft Knowledgebase articles,
>   Microsoft MVPs, and other important
>   support forums, that will assist you
>   in repairing problems with your
>   system. Although this tool is
>   ordinarily meant for power users,
>   technicians, and administrators, it is
>   quite safe to use even without
>   technical guidance (although guidance
>   is recommended). Simply choose the
>   solutions you wish to apply via
>   checkmarks, and click GO. There are
>   other buttons and tools present on the
>   main dialog as well, such as the
>   policy scanner. All tools and
>   checkmarks identify their purpose when
>   you mouse over them.

See [this article](http://www.timeatlas.com/useful_utilities/free/dial_a_fix_repairs_windows_update_problems) for some more information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the "Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer" which is available here from the Microsoft website [MBSA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184924.aspx)

It's a little bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut for the minor problem you are experiencing, but the useful thing about this tool is that it provides links to the windows updates that it thinks your machine is lacking, so you can download each of them individually and install them.

Answer (score 0):

First see if you have any applications using SQL Express, you can look in C:\ProgramFiles, find the Microsoft SQL folder, then go thru and find the data folder. Look at the dates to see if and of the DBs are current. If they are not then uninstall and install the latest version of SQL Express 2005 if you still want it. If something is using it then your best option is to try and apply the SQL Express service pack manually.

Answer (score -1):

Baring solving the issue, you can at least prevent the prompt coming up by hiding the update.

1. Click Start, click Windows Update.
2. Locate the update in question.
3. Check the box to hide the update.

You should no longer be prompted to install it.

Comment: @Grant Palin: Thanks, but it would merely hide it and continue to remember somewhere that this install is still "pending". Is there anyway, that I can ensure it is removed, so there are no more traces of it.

Comment: Well, then I imagine the best thing to do would be to solve the problem. i.e. Figure out why the update won't install. I'm afraid I've no help for that bit of it. Good luck! :)

Comment: Actually, for what it is worth, SQL Server [2005|2008] have been troublesome for me in the past. Actually installing them, installing service packs, and installing updates have all caused me some grief. Can't remember what I did to resolve them, so no help here, but the point is: you are not alone!